# Quick Path (swipe type) on iPhone: How do I continue writing another word/letter without adding a space after the first word?

Tags: ios

I use Quick Path when I write on my iPhone (iOS 16.1). I often find myself being forced to go back and edit out spaces between words and characters. (The fastest way I've found to go back and delete a space is holding the space key and swipe to the space and remove it with the correction key -- this is a bit quicker than trying to click on the space in the text directly.)

Examples when I get a space and don't want it:

- Writing an e-mail address in a search box: `info @example. com -- info@example.com`.
- When writing words in Swedish. In Swedish many combinations of words should be written together. The word combination will often not be found in the dictionary, while the components of the combination will.  So I have to swipe the components separately and then remove the spaces in-between: `vädersols himmel -- vädersolshimmel`.

**Is there any way to continue on a new word without adding a space when using Quick Path?**

**If not, is there a simpler way to edit out the space?**

Comment: One workaround is to add the words in question to *text replacements*.